# getMeasuredHeight() of Textview returned wrong value

Tags: android

I call all the mentioned methods right after the onMeasure() of TextView's parent layout returned, like the following:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int mh = mTextView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int h = mTextView.getLineCount() * mTextView.getLineHeight();
}
```

mh is wrong and shorter than h, does anyone know why, thanks?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

  mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int mh = mTextView.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int h = mTextView.getLineCount() * mTextView.getLineHeight();
                }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, within the onGlobalLayout(), value of mh is changed and a little bigger than h, which means the MeasuredHeight still changes after Measure processing done. So the question is, when will the MeasuredHeight be truely available?

Comment: @jacky0karl If you call `setIncludeFontPadding(false);` then they will be equal.